How to automatically change translation on all components when different language selected
I have a select drop down on a navbar which allows the user to select a different language. When the user selects a different language all text in the nav bar component gets translated, but no text in other displayed components is translated.
How do I get text is all displayed components to automatically translate to new language when the user selects a different language.
Here is the code that is called when the user selects a different language from the select dropdown on the Navbar:
changeLanguage(event : any ): void
  {
    const languageKey: string = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.stateStorageService.storeLocale(languageKey);
    this.translateService.use(languageKey);
  }

Here is the Navbar component html
    <button (click)="toggleSidebar()">Toggle Tree</button>
    <button (click)="logout()" id="logout" data-cy="logout">
        <span jhiTranslate="global.menu.account.logout">Log out</span>
    </button>
    <div class="language-selector">
        <label for="language">Languages:</label>
        <select (change)="changeLanguage($event)">
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="es">Spanish</option>
        </select>
    </div>

When selecting Spanish the logout button changes to spanish
Here is the html of the component which is displayed below the NavBar:
<p><span jhiTranslate="compassApp.organization.home.defaultText">Select an organization level to begin.</span></p>
<p>{{ "compassApp.organization.home.defaultText" | translate }}</p>

When the user changes the selected langage to spanish the text in the component below the NavBar does not change
Here is the i18n/en/organization.json
{
  "compassApp": {
    "organization": {
      "home": {
        "title": "Organizations",
        "refreshListLabel": "Refresh list",
        "createLabel": "Create a new Organization",
        "createOrEditLabel": "Create or edit a Organization",
        "notFound": "No Organizations found",
        "defaultText": "Select an organization level to begin."
      },
      "created": "A new Organization is created with identifier {{ param }}",
      "updated": "A Organization is updated with identifier {{ param }}",
      "deleted": "A Organization is deleted with identifier {{ param }}",
      "delete": {
        "question": "Are you sure you want to delete Organization {{ id }}?"
      },
      "detail": {
        "title": "Organization"
      },
      "id": "ID",
      "modId": "Mod Id",
      "name": "Name",
      "modTs": "Mod Ts",
      "contactEmail": "Contact Email",
      "address": "Address",
      "organizationAppOption": "Organization App Option",
      "organizationEntityName": "Organization Entity Name",
      "organizationLists": "Organization Lists",
      "organizationHierarchy": "Organization Hierarchy"
    }
  }
}

Here is the i18n/es/organization.json
{
  "compassApp": {
    "Organización": {
      "home": {
        "title": "Organizacións",
        "refreshListLabel": "Refrescar lista",
        "createLabel": "Crear nuevo Organización",
        "createOrEditLabel": "Crear o editar Organización",
        "notFound": "Ningún Organizacións encontrado",
        "defaultText": "Seleccione un nivel de organización para comenzar."
      },
      "created": "Un nuevo Organización ha sido creado con el identificador {{ param }}",
      "updated": "Un Organización ha sido actualizado con el identificador {{ param }}",
      "deleted": "Un Organización ha sido eliminado con el identificador {{ param }}",
      "delete": {
        "question": "¿Seguro que quiere eliminar Organización {{ id }}?"
      },
      "detail": {
        "title": "Organización"
      },
      "id": "ID",
      "modId": "Mod Id",
      "name": "Name",
      "modTs": "Mod Ts",
      "contactEmail": "Contact Email",
      "address": "Address",
      "OrganizaciónAppOption": "Organización App Option",
      "OrganizaciónEntityName": "Organización Entity Name",
      "OrganizaciónLists": "Organización Lists",
      "OrganizaciónHierarchy": "Organización Hierarchy"
    }
  }
}

Compared what I did with the CRUD components created by jHipster. The JHipster CRUD apps have their text translated while the component I added does not.

I think your keys should remain static. Eg. i18n/es/organization.json it should be compassApp -> Organization  and the value can be in Spanish. Otherwise it won't be able to distinguish the keys for apply the translate pipe. Also, your keys are not consistent. In English version it is organization while in Spanish version it is Organization

Thanks @Avilon, I had translated the word organization to the Spanish version by accident. Correcting the IDs in the JSON Spanish/es file fixed my issue. Question about your comment about "should remain static". I don't understand what you are saying, could you provide more insight?
